# Question about proof on basis

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I found this proof online, but I have a bit of trouble understanding it.

---

Question:

Let X be a set, and let $B \subseteq \mathcal P \left({X}\right)$. Define

$B^* =${ $U \subseteq X:$ There is an index set $I$ and $U_{i} \in B$ for each $i \in I$ with $U = \bigcup\limits_{i\in I} U_{i}$ }.

Informally, we think of $B^*$ as "the closure of $B$ under arbitrary unions."

If  $B \subseteq \mathcal P \left({X}\right)$, we say that $B$ is a basis on X, if for any $U, V \in B$ and any $x \in U \cap V$, there is $W \in B$ with $x \in W$ and $W \subseteq U \cap V.$

Let X be a set and $B$ a basis on X.

Prove by induction on $k$ that if $U_{0},...,U_{k-1} \in B$ and $U_{0} \cap...\cap U_{k-1} \in B$, then there is $W \in B$ with $x \in W$ and $W \subseteq U_{0} \cap...\cap U_{k-1}$.

Then, prove that $B^*$ is a topology on X.

Answer:

The induction on $k$ is standard: You can start with $k=1$ (we then have one set and the statement is trivially true). Assume truth for $k \ge 1$. For $k+1$, write $U_0 \cap \ldots \cap U_{(k+1)-1}$ as $(U_0 \cap \ldots U_{k-1}) \cap U_k$, and apply the hypothesis for the left hand side, and the given base property for the conclusion.

To check we have a topology, show that the property from the induction shows that $B^\ast$ is closed under finite intersections. That it is closed under unions is true by construction almost; Taking the index set $I = \emptyset$ ensures that $\emptyset \in B^\ast$.

I don't see how $X \in B^\ast$ in general, as we could take $B = \emptyset$, and then $B^\ast = \{\emptyset\}$ is not a topology. We need to assume that $\cup B = X$ as well.

---

I'm having trouble understanding the part "To check we have a topology, show that the property from the induction shows that $B^\ast$ is closed under finite intersections. That it is closed under unions is true by construction almost". How does the property from induction show that $B^\ast$ is closed under finite intersections? Why is $B^\ast$ closed under unions true by construction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construction shows that for any point in the intersection, there is a basic open set containing the point and being under the intersetion. To get precisely the intersection, just think of all the points and use the closedness under arbitrary unions.

$B^*$ is always closed under arbitrary unions by the definition. And the union completetion also preserves the “preintersetion” property.

Aside: There are three levels: a subbasis – that is an arbitrary set, a basis – set satisfying the “preintersection” property and covering the whole space, and a topology. You get a topology from basis just by closing under arbitrary intersections. You also get a basis from subbasis by closing under finite intersections – in this step, you get $X ∈ B$ as empty intersection.